# Springboot error handling HttpServerErrorException, /error, etc

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm having a bit of trouble getting a complete error handling solution.  I've created a @ControllerAdvice class that catches Exceptions and QueryTimeException.  However, the 404 Not Found message does not go to my custom page.  And the HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT doesn't get routed properly. However, HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT and Exceptions do get routed correctly.

Here's my Error Controller.  What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyErrorController.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.GatewayTimeout.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)
    public String gatewayTimeout() {
        return "errors/error-timeout";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(QueryTimeoutException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
    public String requestTimeout() {
        return "errors/error-timeout";
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(value = {HttpClientErrorException.class, Exception.class})
    public String handleExceptions() {
        return  "errors/error";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleErrors(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {
        return  "errors/error";
    }

    // This method is deprecated, so do not add the @Override annotation
    // However, the method must remain while the Spring team has not yet removed it from the ErrorController interface
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

}
```

I've added the following to application.properties:

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
server.error.path=/error
```

To test the above, I added the following methods to a Controller.

```
    @GetMapping("/throw504")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> throwGatewayTimeout() {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT);
    }

    @GetMapping("/throw408")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> throwResponseTimeout() {
        throw new QueryTimeoutException();
    }

    @GetMapping("/throw500")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> throwNotImplemented() {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
    }
```

So I test by running my app, the navigating to localhost:8080/throw408 (I get the error-timeout page), localhost:8080/throw500 (I get the error page), which are both correct.

I then test localhost:8080/throw504 which incorrectly opens the error page, not error-timeout as I expected.  I then test localhost:8080/jskld, which displays a generic 404 page, not the error page I expected.

Comment: please also add the exception handler that you have for `HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED` as you say it already works

Comment: have you checked my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze this a bit more, and you will probably see the error in your code.

```
 @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.GatewayTimeout.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)
    public String gatewayTimeout() {
        return "errors/error-timeout";
    }
```

The exception handler waits for an instance of `GatewayTimeout.class` to handle this exception.

When you create this exception in your controller though

```
@GetMapping("/throw504")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> throwGatewayTimeout() {
        throw new HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT); <------
    }
```

If you inspect this class you will find

```
public class HttpServerErrorException extends HttpStatusCodeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2915754006618138282L;

    public HttpServerErrorException(HttpStatus statusCode) {
        super(statusCode);
    }
```

So the constructor that you use returns back a `HttpServerErrorException.class`

Not a `GatewayTimeout.class`

`GatewayTimeout.class` is a static nested class which extends `HttpServerErrorException.class`.

```
public static final class GatewayTimeout extends HttpServerErrorException {
        private GatewayTimeout(String statusText, HttpHeaders headers, byte[] body, @Nullable Charset charset) {
            super(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT, statusText, headers, body, charset);
        }
```

If you look closer in `HttpServerErrorException.class` there is a constructor that creates an instance of `GatewayTimeout.class`

One way would be to use the constructor

```
HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT,"status text", new HttpHeaders(), new byte[] {}, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

This will return you an exception instance of `GatewayTimeout.class` which spring would probably be able to match.

So your controller must be adapted to be something like

```
  @GetMapping("/throw504")
  public ResponseEntity<Void> throwGatewayTimeout() {
    throw HttpServerErrorException.create(HttpStatus.GATEWAY_TIMEOUT,"status text", new HttpHeaders(), new byte[] {}, Charset.defaultCharset());
   }
```

In the end the point is that `GatewayTimeout.class` extends from `HttpServerErrorException`. So this means that `GatewayTimeout.class` is an `HttpServerErrorException`, but an `HttpServerErrorException` would not be for sure a  `GatewayTimeout.class`.